# Identify generator type given resulting sequence only

Tags: algorithm, generator, formula

Not sure how realistic this is, but anyway, say, I have sequence of some numbers :

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21
```

I am a human and for me it is obvious that this is Fibonacci sequence.

**Question :** is there some programmatic way to determine nature of the generator that created this sequence and generate next value in this sequence? Is it possible to determine formula that was used to generate selected sequence, at least with some approximation?

Comment: You say 'obvious', but to *me* it's pretty 'obvious' that your sequence is `ceiling(e^((n-1)/2))`...

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

There are infinite number of formulas that generate infinite number of results.

I could say, even, that the next number in your sequence [is actually 42](http://juanlopes.net/actually42/#1%2C%201%2C%202%2C%203%2C%205%2C%208%2C%2013%2C%2021/false/false).

---

To be fair, this isn't a silly question at all. There is a whole field of study that try to interpolate and predict the behavior of functions based on examples. It is called [machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning).

But it is not possible to predict the behavior of an unknown function without any further information about the function itself, by the very reason I said before.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. As already observed, there are an infinite number of possible answers. However, it is possible to check certain types of generator to see whether they're capable of explaining the known values.

E.g. polynomials can be tested by looking at nth differences. Other types of generator can be tested by treating the sequence as coefficients of a generating function and looking at nth derivatives of that g.f.

See the description of the [OEIS Superseeker](https://oeis.org/demos.html) for a brief discussion of some relevant ideas, and check out the academic literature (RATE, GFUN, [extensions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702086)).